# select strings bigger than tresh

Tags: r, substring

I have a stringset like this

```
genome
 A DNAStringSet instance of length x
          width seq                                                               
    [1]     1003 GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACTGA...AGGTTTTCAGAAAAAGCAGAAGA 
    [2]     150 TATATATATATAGTCAATTCGAGG...CTATTCCAGAGTTTCCTTGCAAA 
    [3]     1619 ATAGACATACACACAAATATTTTT...TATTTATACATATATATATATAT 
    [4]     359 TCACCAGTGGCAGCCGCGGCTACA...GTACAACGACCCTGATGACTCCG
```

I would to select only strings bigger than tresh = 1000
I've tried

```
genome[filter(width(genome) >=1000]
```

BUt this does not give the correct solution. 
I'll expect the output like this:

```
genome
  A DNAStringSet instance of length x
           width seq                                                               
     [1]     1003 GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACTGA...AGGTTTTCAGAAAAAGCAGAAGA  
     [3]     1619 ATAGACATACACACAAATATTTTT...TATTTATACATATATATATATAT
```

anyone can sugest me a working script?

Comment: Would you give us a `dput` of the data? or `dput(head(data))`. Anyway I think you may do `genome[ genome$width >= 1000]`.

Comment: this solution doesn't  work because I used a DNAstringset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case you need `nchar` which counts the number of characters in a character string. 
So try this:

```
genome[nchar(genome$seq) >= 1000, ]
```

If width is the number characters you can also select the right entries like this:

```
genome[genome$width >= 1000, ]
```

In your question you used the `filter` function from the `dpylr` package: this can be done like so:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(genome, width >= 1000)
```

or

```
filter(genome, nchar(seq) >= 1000)
```

Comment: I think that it is a stringset, so it isn't not possible to use dplyr. Infact it reminds me this error Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('DNAStringSet', 'XStringSet', 'XRawList', 'XVectorList', 'List', 'Vector', 'list_OR_List', 'Annotated')"

Comment: Ok what about the other methods. If they do not work please post the output `dput(head(genome))`.

Comment: please post the output inside your question and not as a comment

Comment: sorry, I solved the problem using this script!  genome[width(genome) >= 1000,]